# Drupal 6 Core Update Not Updating

Tags: 6, updating

I am running Drupal 6 and have attempted to update the Core about 5 times recently, and it continues to tell me I haven't updated it. I AM running update.php, and doing it the way it's always worked before. But Drupal is not perceiving that I've done it.

No problems with individual modules updates. Drupal and following a procedure I've followed numerous times before, successfully. Not using Drush, but am using command line.

Comment: When you say you are not using Drush, but using the command line, can you provide the command you are using to upgrade? I strongly recommend using Drush.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use drush.

Goto your project source folder from terminal.

Use the following command to upgrade.

drush pm-update projects

Ex: `root@karthik$ drush pm-update projects drupal-6.34`

This will update your drupal core to 6.4 version.